# Recycle sitecore item with context user

Tags: sitecore

I want to recycle sitecore item with current login user programmatically. I did recycle with below code with non admin but it is no showing in recycle bin  because is recycle by anonymous. How can we update statistic while recycling sitecore item.
below is my code

```
 using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
  using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(item, true,false))
                    {
                        if (Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.RecycleBinActive)
                            item.Recycle();
                        else
                            item.Delete(); 
                    }
    }
```

Comment: P.S. I can see recycled item in recycle bin from admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test if Recycle bin is active. Just call `Recycle()` - It'll do recycle or delete for you depending on the configuration. You don't need an `EditContext` either to perform the deletion.

If the current user have delete access to the item, you don't need the `SecurityDisabler` either. If you're running this code from another user, you can use the `UserSwitcher` to get into the correct user context:

```
using (new UserSwitcher(theUser)) {
   item.Recycle();
}
```